# Could not create query metamodel Spring Data JPA repository (Weird behaviour)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am getting an unexpected error in my JPA repository. Spring cannot create repo bean because of an exception related to JPA.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract com.xxxxx.entities.Foo com.xxxxx.repositories.FooRepository.findByCourierId(java.lang.Long)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract com.xxxxx.entities.Foo com.xxxxx.repositories.FooRepository.findByCourierId(java.lang.Long)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:97)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:367)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:190)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [courierId] on this ManagedType [com.xxxxx.core.models.XXXObject]
```

Code for my repo is as follows :

```
public interface FooRepository extends XXXRepository<Foo> {

    Foo findByCourierId(Long courierId);

    @Query("SELECT CA " +
        "FROM Foo CA " +
        "WHERE CA.courier.id IN (?1)")
    List<Foo> findByCourierIds(List<Long> courierIds);
}
```

Now the weird thing is that it error displays for the first query which was working perfectly find before added the second method, if i remove the second query, the code works fine.

Code for the entity goes something like this

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends XXXObject {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "courier_id")
    private Courier courier;
....
```

Comment: `Foo` does not have an attribute `courierId`, only `courier`. Unless your `Courier` class has an attribute `id`, the exception is exactly telling you what the problem is.

Comment: but i dont understand why it works if i remove the second query. `findByCourierIds`. That was my question, it was able to map `courierId` from `courier` table before i added the second query

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
public interface FooRepository extends XXXRepository<Foo> {
```

Can you use JPARepository

```
 public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
```

Comment: yes but the `XXXRepository` already extends `JpaRepository<Foo, Long>`

Comment: Sorry. This was not mentioned in question so was not aware of this .